# Calculating Laplace transform of fractional power law

Tags: laplace-transform

I wish to calculate the laplace transform of following function,

$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{1+p (t/\tau)^\beta}
$$
where $\beta < 1$. Any ideas of how to go about the calculation?

Comment: There is a closed-form expression in terms of the Fox H-function, if that would help.

Comment: I guess it would be useful too. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laplace transform can be evaluated as an integral of a product of two Meijer G-functions. For $\beta > 0$, we obtain
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-s t}} {1 + t^\beta} dt =
\int_0^\infty
 G_{1, 1}^{1, 1} \left( t^\beta \middle| {0 \atop 0} \right)
 G_{0, 1}^{1, 0} \left( s t \middle| {- \atop 0} \right) dt =
\frac 1 s H_{2, 1}^{1, 2} \left( s^{-\beta} \middle|
 {(0, 1), (0, \beta) \atop (0, 1) } \right).$$
For $\beta < 0$,
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-s t}} {1 + t^\beta} dt =
\int_0^\infty
 G_{1, 1}^{1, 1} \left( t^{-\beta} \middle| {1 \atop 1} \right)
 G_{0, 1}^{1, 0} \left( s t \middle| {- \atop 0} \right) dt =
\frac 1 s H_{2, 1}^{1, 2} \left( s^\beta \middle|
 {(1, 1), (0, -\beta) \atop (1, 1) } \right),$$
which, incidentally, is the same as formally extending the first result to negative $\beta$.

The resulting Fox H-function can be converted to a G-function when $\beta$ is rational.

Comment: This is an interesting insight! Thank you!

Comment: I have a doubt about this  result. I think it is valid only if $\beta=1$. Could you derive step by step?

Comment: @user48672 If you're testing the result numerically, what values of $\beta$ and $s$ are you taking? Most likely the issue is in the numerical evaluation of the H-function. To evaluate the integral, we find $\mathcal M[t \mapsto e^{-t}]$, which gives Euler's integral of the second kind, and $\mathcal M[t \mapsto 1/(1 + t^\beta)]$, which reduces to Euler's integral of the first kind, and apply the [Mellin convolution method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3104763).