# Laplace transform of the function $\frac{1}{1 + t^q}$

Tags: laplace-transform, mittag-leffler-function

I am stuck with calculating the Laplace transform of
$$
 f(t)=\frac{1}{1 + t^q}, \quad q<1
$$
Is it related to the Mittag-Leffler function $E_{a,a}$?

Comment: $\mathcal L[f]$ can be evaluated by applying the [Mellin convolution method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2930193).

Comment: I have a doubt about the result in the post. I think it is valid only if β=1.